Why does my article have the wrong URL?
I have a really weird issue that I haven't seen before.  Obviously I am blaming the client.
On this page: https://tekexpress.co.uk/news?start=12 all of the articles click through.
But the "7 reasons why our clients choose Tek" is a 404.
If I turn off URL rewriting it clicks through fine.
Also if I change the alias that doesn't change anything.
It's going to the wrong URL structure.  Instead of /news/ in the URL it's got /headlines/ which was the old URL structure.
I have changed the menu alias from "headlines" to "news"
and I have changed the category from "headlines" to "news".
I have currently disabled the redirects plugin.
Hovering on the link shows the correct URL with /news/ in it.
I've cleaned LiteSpeed cache although I haven't installed that plugin.
I have disabled and renabled Redis, although I'm not 100% sure if there's a way to clean that cache.
I've installed Regular Labs cache cleaner and cleaned cache.
I've cleared YooTheme Cache.
The Joomla Page Cache plugin is disabled.
Where would it be getting this old information from?

I worked it out, it was this rule in my .htaccess file
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)-(.*)$ /headlines/$2 [L,R=302]

